# Substitution in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, unification

I have to tell whether or not the following pairs of expressions unify.

This is the task :

```
f(g(a, X), g(X, b)) = f(g(a, b, c, d))
```

I know that given a set of expressions, a substitution is a unifier for that set if all the terms of the set are the same given the substitution, consequently a set is only unifiable if there is a substitution that is a unifier for that set. The problem is that I cannot find a solution for this task and say with certainty whether or not there is a unifier.

Comment: Is it really `f(g(a,b,c,d))` on the righthand side, or should it be `f(g(a,b),g(c,d))` ?

Comment: As I wrote : f ( g (a,b,c,d) )